# Marker symbols from a WMS not behaving with a rotated data frame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, markers, data-frame, rotate

I have unchecked "Rotate marker symbols with dataframe" in ArcGIS, which works as normal for marker symbols from locally sourced shapefiles, however, the WMS layer marker symbols do not respect the setting.

Can this be fixed in the GIS software's settings, or possibly in the map server file that defines the WMS symbols?